# Escaping last bg job pid ($!) on mac osx shell

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to run a background job and get its PID from the bash command line, such as this:

```
$ cat &
$ echo $!
```

These two commands work perfectly, but if I try to inline them into one line I run into problems with bash history expansion conflicting with `$!`:

```
$ (cat &); echo $!;
-bash: !: event not found
```

I have tried various types of quoting around the exclamation mark, but the most I could get was for echo to display the literal string `"$!"`.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to have it as an oneliner? Anyway, you don't need to write `;` after a `&` because the ampersand is itself an command delimiter. This means that you can run `cat & echo $!`.

Comment: Easiest answer is to just turn off history expansion. It's off by default in scripts, and with modern readline features, there's not much need to have it interactively either. (Also, what @marbu said re: `&`).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses. That `&` is a command separator is new to me, thank you for pointing that out.
As for why do I need to have it as a oneliner? No real reason, I just enjoy messing around.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the first command in the background with the `&` delimiter. You can easily capture the `pid` of the backgrouded process by assigning `$!` to a variable to later use to kill the process (or you can write it to a tmp file): E.g.

```
cat & savpid=$!; ...do stuff...; kill $savpid (or kill %1 if no other jobs running)
```

You also have to option to check the status of your backgrounded process with the `jobs` command to list backgrounded jobs, and the use of the `fg` (foreground) command to bring the command to the foreground. Let us know if you have any further questions.

In order to accomplish what you are attempting, you must redirect `stderr` and `stdout` before backgrounding the process:

```
cat 2>&1 & echo $!
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but you completely missed the point since: 1) I already know what `&` and `$!` do, and; 2) your code sample does not work on a Mac OSX terminal, which is actually the point of me posting a question in the first place.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding. In your one-line command, you should redirect both stderr and stdout before you background. E.g. `cat 2>&1 & echo $!` added to answer.